# modify variable in outer scope of a Kubernetes Helm template

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I can append characters to a variable (i.e. concatenate) in Helm like that

```
{{- $myvar := "foo" }}
{{- $myvar := printf "%s-%s" $myvar "bar" }}
myvar: {{ $myvar }} # myvar: foo-bar
```

I do need this concatenation when iterating over files. Unfortunately - probably due to the variable scope - changing the variable is local to the scope. Let's use *tuples* for the sake of simplicity:

```
data:
{{- $myvar := "foo" }}
{{- $myvar := printf "%s-%s" $myvar "bar" }}
{{- range tuple "vala" "valb" "valc" }}
  {{- $myvar := printf "%s-%s" $myvar . }}
  {{ . }}: {{ $myvar }}
{{- end }}
  myvar: {{ $myvar }}
```

is rendered as

```
data:
  vala: foo-bar-vala
  valb: foo-bar-valb
  valc: foo-bar-valc
  myvar: foo-bar
```

How do I get the code rewritten, so I can actually append values to the `$myvar` variable in the outer scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that due to usage of `:=` operator a new `$myvar` variable is declared and modified in the inner scope of the `range` operator which has no effect on the `$myvar` variable declared in the outer scope

To achieve modification of the `$myvar` from outer scope the `=` operator needs to be used.

So this template

```
data:
{{- $myvar := "foo" }}
{{- $myvar := printf "%s-%s" $myvar "bar" }}
{{- range tuple "vala" "valb" "valc" }}
  {{- $myvar = printf "%s-%s" $myvar . }}
  {{ . }}: {{ $myvar }}
{{- end }}
  myvar: {{ $myvar }}
```

is rendered as

```
data:
  vala: foo-bar-vala
  valb: foo-bar-vala-valb
  valc: foo-bar-vala-valb-valc
  myvar: foo-bar-vala-valb-valc
```